# Why do I get this JavaScript ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am doing wrong. I try to make object but when i try to initialize i get this error in console: I try to put all in document.ready and whitout that but dont work. In both case i have some error. Am new sorry for dumb question

```
ReferenceError: Circle is not defined
    var obj = new Circle;
```

JS

```
$(function(){
        var Circle = {

                init: function() {
                    console.log("Circle initialized");
                }     
        };

});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/circle.js"></script>

        <script>           

               $(document).ready(function(){
                   var obj = new Circle;

                   obj.init();
               })

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" >TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NEW UPDATE**

```
$(function(){

        window.Circle = {

                init: function() {
                    console.log("Circle initialized");
                }     
        };
       window.Circle.init();
});
```

....

```
  <head>

     <script>           

        window.Circle().init();

    </script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 9):

You've defined your "Circle" function **inside** another function — the anonymous function you pass in as a a "ready" handler. Therefore, that symbol ("Circle") is private to that function, and not visible to the other code.

You can make it global like this:

```
window.Circle = {
  // ...
};
```

You could also add it to the jQuery namespace (may or may not be appropriate; depends on what you're doing), or you could develop your own namespace for your application code. Or, finally, you could consider combining your jQuery "ready" code so that the "Circle" object and the code that uses it all appears in the same handler.

*edit* — *another* possibility is to move your "Circle" declaration completely out of the "ready" handler. If all you do is initialize that object, and your property values don't require any work that requires the DOM or other not-yet-available resources, you can just get rid of the `$(function() { ... })` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But when i define window i again have TypeError: window.Circle is undefined

Comment: @Jony well it could be (not sure why) that your handler in "circle.js" is being called after the other handler. If all you do is define that "Circle" object, the code doesn't really need to be in a "ready" handler at all.  I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Sorry for wasting time. But i do what u say. In my object Circle i add `window.Circle {}` and in my ***head*** i put whitout `document.ready()` function   `window.Circle.init();`

Comment: @Jony maybe you should edit your question to show your revised code. This is a very simple problem and there is no reason it should not work.

Comment: Just a seconds to try again all what u  say

Comment: @Jony hey sorry, I missed your other mistake - "Circle" is not a function; it's just an object. Your other code is trying to call it as a function with `new`.  You can only use `new` with functions.

Comment: I update my post. Am prob. idiot for this. if is this so eazy problem

Comment: @Jony your second piece of code is trying to use `window.Circle` as a function: should be just `window.Circle.init()`.

Comment: I detect problem. I put object declaration in `<head>` tag and initialize him. WHen is declaration in `Head` tag all work good. This dont work only when i move my object declaration in other test.js file.

Answer (score 1):

1) you are assigning Circle in a function context, not as a global. You can only use it there unless you expose it to global.
2) you are calling Circle as a constructor, but Circle is not a function.

This solves both issues:

```
var Circle = function () {};
Circle.prototype.init = function () {
    console.log('Circle initialized.');
};
var obj = new Circle();
obj.init();
```

Comment: Wow I totally missed this!  Good call.

Comment: Yeah i know that. I put Object Circle in separate file. and in head tag i put object instance and again i have stupid error.

Comment: In your new code: window.Circle().init(); -- window.Circle is not a function, you can use just window.Circle.init()